Is it possible to use a CancellationToken with ASP.NET Web Methods?
I am working with an ASP.NET Web Forms application that uses WebMethod for server-side methods, and I want to implement cancellation functionality similar to how a CancellationToken works in asynchronous operations.
My goal is to be able to cancel long-running WebMethod executions on the server when the client cancels the request or when a timeout occurs.
I know that CancellationToken works well with async methods, but WebMethod doesn't support async/await patterns directly.
Is there a way to implement something similar to CancellationToken in a traditional WebMethod? Specifically, is it possible to interrupt the execution of a WebMethod on the server if the client cancels the request, or if there’s a timeout?
What would be the best way to handle this scenario in ASP.NET Web Forms?
